# Optional jDBI parameter

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

Is it possible to have optional (null) parameters with jDBI queries?  I'm attempting to get optional parameters working in a database query.  I am working with dropwizard.

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * \n" +
          "FROM posts \n" +
          "WHERE (:authorId IS NULL OR :authorId = author_id)")
public List<Post> findAll(@Bind("authorId") Optional<Long> authorId);
```

The query works when an authorId is passed, but gives me this error when it is NULL:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

This is the resource route I am calling from:

```
@GET
public ArrayList<Post> getPosts(@QueryParam("authorId") Long authorId)
{
    return (ArrayList<Post>)postDao.findAll(Optional.fromNullable(authorId));
}
```

From what I've read, this is possible to do, so I'm guessing I am missing something or have an obvious mistake.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

FYI - I have also tried it without guava Optional (which is supported by dropwizard) -- just sending a authorId as a Long that is null.  This also works as long as it's not null.

Comment: You should check [jdbi community](http://jdbi.org/community.html)

Comment: Thanks @zloster, I posted this there as well.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use java8 version of `DBIFactory` on your application class. It provides java 8 optional support as well as joda LocalDateTime.

Gradle dependency: (convert it to maven, if you're using maven)

`compile 'io.dropwizard.modules:dropwizard-java8-jdbi:0.7.1`'

and make sure you import `io.dropwizard.java8.jdbi.DBIFactory` on Applicaiton class and use it under run.

```
public void run(T configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDatabase(), "database");
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.  The only issue is that I have used guava optional throughout my application.  As long is dropwizard and JDBI are fully compatible with java 8 optional I don't see it being a problem.

Comment: I see. Then you can simply copy the code from the java8 solution and change the Optionals to Guava. see these two:
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8/blob/master/dropwizard-java8-jdbi/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/java8/jdbi/DBIFactory.java
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8/blob/master/dropwizard-java8-jdbi/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/java8/jdbi/args/OptionalArgumentFactory.java

Comment: I only get `org.skife.jdbi.v2.MappingRegistry$1: No mapper registered for java.util.Optional` for optional return values.

Comment: Are you using the DBIFactory directly or have you copied the solution from github? If you're doing it manually, then you need to register OptionalContainerFactory as well (https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8/blob/master/dropwizard-java8-jdbi/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/java8/jdbi/OptionalContainerFactory.java) for return values.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed for me was adding the type hints when using the optional inside my query template.

Example:

```
 "AND (:columnName::uuid IS NULL OR columnName= :columnName::uuid) "
```